# Applying stashed commit '...' failed due to 'Applying... egit error in eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, egit

i am trying to apply a stash that I did through eclipse but I am getting the next error message :
Applying stashed commit '...' failed due to 'Applying stashed changes resulted in a conflict'.
how can I resolve the conflicts in eclipse ? tried to open sync view but I didn't see anything that need to be resolved...
using eclipse kepler.

Answer (score 9):

I had this happen when I included untracked files in my stash. I did a reset HARD to clear my working copy, then ran this from the command-line (the stash I wanted was on top of the stack):

```
git stash apply --index
```

Now I see my modified files, and my "untracked" files reappear. Not sure why the GUI doesn't work.

Using Eclipse Luna.

Comment: Using Neon.2, also failed from EGit and worked for command-line (I didn't do any reset)

Comment: In my case this worked however if the stash was not the latest stash then you would specify which stash `git stash apply stash@{2}`

Comment: For me, the trick was doing the HARD reset. After that, applying the stash directly from the GUI worked for me (using Scala IDE, a derivative of Eclipse). Didn't need to apply the stash from the terminal.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem when I stashed some work I was doing in order to do some last minute, urgent bug fixing.

In order to overcome this situation, I did the following in Eclipse (note that I used Luna version):

- Right click on the Eclipse project -> Team -> Show in Repositories View
- Find the "*References*" folder in the Repositories View, right click it, then select the "*New Branch...*" option.
- Create a new branch with the stashed changes.
- Checkout the original branch on which you want to apply the stash
- Merge both branches and resolve conflicts the usual way.

Comment: Easy and fast. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I get this error every time I apply changes from stashed commit in neon.1
Looks like a bug. One of many bugs in egit

Answer (score 1):

This commonly happens when you stash your changes in one branch and apply them on another.

To resolve these conflicts, you need to search for `<<<<<` which are git markers that git uses to tell you where and which branches have the conflicts.

[Here](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/merging-with-a-conflict-conflicts-and-resolutions/)'s an exhaustive link that explains how to resolve the conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have change something and you need to stash this changes then you could apply the other stash.

I have used TortoiseGit and it said me more info about this problem.

Hope it's helps to resolve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If ==>

1. You have misteakenly applied stash changes to other branch
2. Still You can not see the conflicts in file/s
3. Replace with Index/Head doesn't work

Then ==>

Open "Git Staging" view, right click on file  => replace with => Our version <....>.

This works for me. I hope it will work for you.

Comment: This seems to be bug in eclipse. The second time I faced the issue, the solution above didnt worked. But I went to git staging --> right click on conflicted file -->add to index and magic, conflicted filed fixed itselfs.

Answer (score 0):

This could also happen if you have a "dirty" working directory. E.g. modified files you won't intend to commit anyway. If you don't need these changes and want to apply your stash on the last "clean" commit, run `git restore .` After that, you should be able to apply your stash.

Answer (score -1):

in my case in eclipse Oxygen it works if I go to Team>Stashes, click on the stash I want to resume and then in the "Stashed Commit" view click on the small brown and green Icon on the top on the right ("Apply stashed changes").
Very comfortable if you want to switch branches.